# VB-New to VB Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get a couple columns to change within my sheet based on the following code, however I keep receiving an error code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 12 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Cells(Target.Row, 13).Value = Date + Time
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    If Target.Column = 13 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Cells(Target.Row, 14).Value = Date + Time
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error that you receive?

Comment: What is Date? what is Time?

Comment: I suspect that this is actually a question about VBA in Excel, not a question about VB.NET.  If that is true, please fix the tags.

Comment: I apologize, I changed the tag.  I have two columns on the same sheet that when each is update individually, the date and time are recorded in the in the column beside those cells.

Comment: Instead of `= Date + Time` use `= Now()`

Comment: Now its not giving me an error, it's just not doing what it is coded to do.

Comment: That's not the problem, its being able to run both of those codes in the same sheet

Comment: How are you defining `Date` and `Time`? Also, please provide the error message, as that can be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the input, its now working...the End If needed to be removed in the first part. Error on my part.

Answer (score 0):

taking a wild stab but I assume you want to format it as below

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 12 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Cells(Target.Row, 13).Value = Format(DateTime.Now, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    If Target.Column = 13 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Cells(Target.Row, 14).Value = Format(DateTime.Now, "hh:mm:ss")
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```